# WYSIHTML5 formatting not working outside of the editor

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, wysihtml5

I am using the wysihtml5 editor found at:

https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

My problem is that in the editor, when I use the subscript or indent buttons the text is properly displayed inside the text box.  I am then saving this description in a database.  When I pull that data from the database the  tag and  tag does not work.

Here is what it looks like inside the editor:

[image]

Here is what it looks like outside of the editor:

[image]

Here is the generated markup for the first image

[image]

Here is the generated markup for the second image

[image]

It still has the sub and blockquote tag, but it is not working.  Is there any reason why this is?

Edit:

I am doing this in rails and I noticed that the iFrame stuff is not being added to the description when it is outside of the editor.  In the edit mode my rails code looks like this:

```
  .right-side
    %table{:width => "100%"}
      %tr
        %td
          %label.text-title-edit Event description
      %tr
        %td
          = render :partial => "wysihtml5_toolbar"
      %tr
        %td
          = text_area_tag "realm[description]", @realm.description, :id =>  "event_description"
```

Outside of the edit I am simply pulling what is stored in the DB:

```
           .right
              %table
                %tr
                  %td
                    %label.text-title Event description
                %tr
                  %td
                    %label.text-info#event_description_view
                      = @realm.description.html_safe
```

Comment: Can you post the generated markup?

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue to me, no reason why that code, unaffected by CSS, wouldn't display in modern browsers like your first image.  Do you have a live example?

Comment: I do not have a live example, I am thinking that it is not working because of that iframe stuff.

Comment: Is there a way to get wysihtml5 to add css to a specific tag?

Comment: I don't know if there is an "off-the-shelf" way.  My guess though is that there is a reset or some other style that is messing up the `<sub>` tag.  In your element inspector, on the right, there is a `Styles` tab, do you see anything in there that is affecting it? What about the `Computed` tab?

Comment: Wow! I found a user agent style sheet that sets the default styles for the tags.  That is what was screwing up.  I don't know much about CSS yet so I didnt really know where to look!  Thanks!  You are awesome!